# relative import in python 3 error no known parent package

Tags: python-3.x, relative-import

I am trying to import common/util module in my mains under feature1 and feature2 directory. I have used from ..common import util but getting ImportError: attempted relative import with no know parent package.
Is there a way to import common/util inside main.

Directory Stucture

```
common
   __init__.py
   util.py
feature1
   main.py
feature2
   main.py
```

Comment: How do you run the script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is - run your main from the parent directory of common, feature, etc - so:

```
$ ls
common feature1 feature2
$ python -m feature1.main
```

Note there is no `.py` at the end